# Value plus null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following procedure running on SQL SERVER 2005

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[p_shipavgAddOnUpdate]
as
begin
declare @addon decimal(20,2),@FloorPrice decimal(20,2)

update z
set  
@addon = case when pp.mapprice>0
        then 0
        else            
           ( BasePrice + Mktng ) *.027 
-- to allow for a higher sale price than the base price
        end
    ,addon=@addon
    ,@FloorPrice = ( BasePrice + Mktng +  @AddOn )
    ,@FloorPrice =

  CASE WHEN @FloorPrice > COALESCE(pp.mapPrice, 0) 
    THEN  @FloorPrice 
    ELSE    .mapPrice 
  END
,FloorPrice = @FloorPrice
,FloorOffer  = @FloorPrice + FinalShippCost
FROM zshipaverage z
     inner join products p on z.sku = p.sku
        inner join product_pricing pp on p.productid=pp.product
end
```

then the proc gets called from another proc, which runs a bunch of procs, ie

```
exec proc1
exec proc2
```

....
etc

in one proc previous to this one, the baseprice field is set
in the next proc, the Mktng field is set
in this proc the addon, and floorprice are set
so the floorprice is suppose to be = baseprice + Mktng + Addon
after running the proc i ended with a record
as so:

```
baseprice = 6.14
mktng     = 2.13
addon     = NULL
floorprice= 0.00
```

Two questions;
1.- how can i end with a floorprice of 0.00 if addon is null? (nromal ansi default set to 
    value + NULL = NULL)

```
I can't reproduce the effect
```

2.- Am i assured that the procedures in the call proc are running in order?

thnx

Comment: I don't think you should be setting variables in your update statement, then using their values to set column values.  Is the order of operation even defined?

Answer (score 1):

It's right there in your code

```
@FloorPrice =
CASE WHEN  
@FloorPrice > COALESCE(pp.mapPrice, 0) THEN
@FloorPrice ELSE    .mapPrice END
```

You are `NULL` checking  the `pp.mapPrice` before setting the value of `@FloorPrice` which means that `@FloorPrice` will be 0 if any of its constituents are `NULL`

You might also want to replace the other section as follows:

```
, @FloorPrice = (ISNULL(BasePrice,0) +
                 ISNULL(Mktng,0) + 
                 ISNULL(@AddOn,0) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Correction:

```
, @FloorPrice = CASE WHEN @AddOn IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ( BasePrice +
              Mktng+ 
              @AddOn ) END
```

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what salomon is asking for. In the case that `@AddOn` is null, the above will result in `@FloorPrice` being equal to `(BasePrice + Mktng)`. I believe that salomon wants `@FloorPrice` to equal 0.00 in that case.

Comment: Ah, gotcha... Corrected answer